# Tryin to make iconosquare widget responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using iconosquare widget to display pictures on my website(built with bootstrap) and my question is if it is possible to make the widget responsive using bootstrap or another method, because when I access the website from a mobile device everything seems to be responsive but the iconosquare widget.

link to my website: [www.djexotic.cz](http://www.djexotic.cz/#portfolio)

widget code:

```
<iframe src="http://iconosquare.com/widget.php?choice=myfeed&amp;username=rubencgt&amp;show_infos=false&amp;linking=statigram&amp;width=920&amp;height=780&amp;mode=grid&amp;layout_x=5&amp;layout_y=4&amp;padding=10&amp;photo_border=false&amp;background=&amp;text=&amp;widget_border=false&amp;radius=5&amp;border-color=&amp;user_id=290825485&amp;time=1406096883259" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:920px; height:780px;" frameborder="0" height="780" width="920"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove parameter of width and height.
Or try this

```
iframe src="http://iconosquare.com/widget.php?choice=myfeed&amp;username=rubencgt&amp;show_infos=false&amp;linking=statigram&amp;mode=grid&amp;layout_x=5&amp;layout_y=4&amp;padding=10&amp;photo_border=false&amp;background=&amp;text=&amp;widget_border=false&amp;radius=5&amp;border-color=&amp;user_id=290825485&amp;time=1406096883259" 
allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" frameborder="0"
```